# Multiple methods inside one Directive return

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am setting up a base template for my web application using only **One Directive** that has **Multiple Methods** returning different templates.

What I did so far is do it the same as how I call **Services**

> SERVICE

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    let path = "app/api/";

    return {
        getStudentInfo: () => {
            //Some Statement...
        }
    }
})
```

Now, In case on how I currently call Directive. But does not seem to work

> **DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive('baseTemplate', function() {
    let path = "app/templates/"; // my basetemplate path folder

    // I want to call specific methods returning the template I need.
    return {
        getCategory: () => {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                template: '<strong> HELLO WORLD! </strong>'
            }
        },
        getTable: () => {
            return: {
                restrict: 'A',
                template: '<table> SOME DATA! </table>'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This is What I do in calling the the directive

> **HTML**

```
<div base-template.getCategory>
    //The Output should be <strong> HELLO WORLD! </strong>
</div>

<div base-template.getTable> 
    //The same as the above Out should <table> SOME DATA! </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do it this way:

```
<div base-template="getCategory">
    <!-- The Output should be --><strong> HELLO WORLD! </strong>
</div>

<div base-template="getTable"> 
    <!-- The same as the above Out should --><table> SOME DATA! </table>
</div>
```

```
app.directive('baseTemplate', function() {
    let path = "app/templates/"; // my basetemplate path folder

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
            switch (tAttrs.baseTemplate) {
                case: "getCategory":
                   return `<strong> HELLO WORLD! </strong>`;
                case: "getTable":
                   return `<table> SOME DATA! </table>`;
                default:
                   return `<div>No Template Selected</div>`;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The `template` property A function which takes two arguments `tElement` and `tAttrs`  and returns a string value.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-)